# Python For loop and range function

Tags: python, for-loop, range

```
def countMe(num):
    for i in range(0, num, 3):
        print (i)

countMe(18)

def oddsOut(num1, num2):

    for i in range(num1):
        for j in range(num2):
            print(i*j)

oddsOut(3, 8)
```

I don't understand how the range function works:

- in `countMe` shouldn't the code go up till 18 ;
- why is the last number printed in `countMe` 15, and not 18 ;
- why is that in the second function `oddsOut` the function only counts till 7 for j and not 8 even though j is 8 ;
- why is the last number printed in `oddsOut` 14.

Comment: The `stop` parameter (the second one) of range is exclusive not inclusive.

Comment: Almost _all_ ranges things in Python are "half-open", meaning that the start is inclusive and the stop is exclusive—the `range` function, slices, etc. This is explained in the tutorial chapter on [Strings](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings), the first place slices are introduced, and should show up similarly early in any other tutorials/texts/etc.

Comment: If you want it to include 18, maybe just change `num` to `num + 3`

Comment: The only thing in the stdlibs I know, where the end point is included is `random.randint`.

Comment: @user3193087 actually, no. You need to change `num` to `num+1`.

Comment: @zmo that could also work, but since it has a step of 3 the result is the same.

Comment: indeed, but I think your assertion may be misleading.

Comment: It could be, but using the `+3` just makes it easier for me to visualize. It's all preference though.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: … which is a great example, because it explicitly says that it's just an "alias for `randrange(a, b+1)`", and later on shows how `randrange` is the intuitive thing to use. :)

Comment: @abarnert I don't get your point (and/or sarcasm).

Comment: @Hyperboreus: My point is that you're right, there are very few examples in the stdlib, and the fact that the only one that comes to mind basically tells you that it's not useful reinforces that even further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stop parameter in a range does not include that number for example

```
for i in range(0,5):
    print i
```

would print 0-4 but not 5.

Answer (score 4):

well, from the help:

```
>>> help(range)
range(...)
    range([start,] stop[, step]) -> list of integers

    Return a list containing an arithmetic progression of integers.
    range(i, j) returns [i, i+1, i+2, ..., j-1]; start (!) defaults to 0.
    When step is given, it specifies the increment (or decrement).
    For example, range(4) returns [0, 1, 2, 3].  The end point is omitted!
    These are exactly the valid indices for a list of 4 elements.
```

so the last increment is not `stop`, but the last step before `stop`.

> - in countMe shouldn't the code go up till 18 ;
> - why is the last number printed in countMe 15, and not 18 ;
> - why is that in the second function oddsOut the function only founts till 7 for j and not 8 even though j is 8 ;
> - why is the last number printed in oddsOut 14.

more generally speaking the answer to those questions is that in most of the languages, a range is defined as `[start:stop[`, i.e. the last value of the range is never included, and the indexes start always at `0`. The mess being that in a few languages and when working on algorithmics, ranges start at `1` and are inclusive with the last value.

In the end, if you want to include the last value you can do:

```
def closed_range(start, stop, step=1):
    return range(start, stop+1, step)
```

or in your example:

```
>>> def countMe(num):
>>>     for i in range(0, num+1, 3):
>>>         print (i)
>>> 
>>> countMe(18)
0
3
6
9
12
15
18
>>>
```

Comment: `stop-step`? So the last number yielded by `range (0, 100, 7)` would be `93`? (it is `98` actually)

Answer (score 0):

Ranges in Python do *not* include the ending value. This is consistent with slices.

If you need a way to remember this, consider that `range(10)` has 10 elements - the numbers 0 through 9.